Why does OnlyOffice Community Server run as privileged in Docker?
Self hosting a lot of tools here. I learned about OnlyOffice when I installed Document Server and connected it to my Nextcloud.
I kept looking for more around it and found OnlyOffice Community Server which seamed very interesting. Unfortunately, when I looked at it, I saw that it has to be deployed as a privileged container...
To require "privileged" is a No-Go for me and honestly, I think it should be No-Go for basically everyone. When running as privileged, there is no more Docker, container, restriction or anything. The privileged container can do everything like modifying the boot sector, accessing RAM, ... Everything!
See this explaination about it :
Privileged containers and capabilities
So why Community Server is to be deployed as privileged and is there any way to avoid that ?
I did not even tried to install Community Server without the privileged flag because there would be no way to know if it is working properly or not. Because I do not know why the privileged flag is required, I do not know what can be non-functional, risky, unstable, what to test, what to compensate, ...
